# How many humans would it take to fill a vat that is 55.5 feet long, wide, and tall full of blood?

Tags: apocalypse, dragons, vampires, blood, farming

So I am in the process of building this world where this huge(1,296 ft. long) vampiric, demonic(maybe), dragon imprisons(well, its offspring does) humanity in dreamworlds that allow them to farm their blood not only easier, but also make more of it in less time and change its flavor as well. This is done mostly to feed the reptilian captors' mother and master, Drak(that big dragon), as her children hardly eat any(to save it for her). Think of it as *The Matrix* meets *Daybreakers* and *Ancient Aliens*.

Anyway, I was thinking on how many humans it would take to fill this trough/tank/vat used to fed it to the brim with blood, at least for 1 go 'round. I could change it if it seems like too few to be believable, but I am not necessarily looking to have to use like a billion or something folks, this might just be an Earthlike setting, not our world.

Anyway, here is the context to help you figure it out more effectively:

- The trough/tank/vat is 55.5 feet tall, wide, and long.
- Humans are kept from aging, made to recoup faster, and mostly feed(they will feed them...other things from time to time) by pumping them with a special substance made from the Drak's saliva.
- This saliva lets them take up to around 80-90% of a human's blood without ill effect. Normal blood volume and red blood cell count will return around in around 6 days.
- I understand blood volume varies from person to person due to age, size, and sex, but for the sake of this question, let us just say the 'bleeders' are adults of average size and are in their 30s.

So, how many humans are need to fill Drak's bowl at least once? I should be able to take it from there

Comment: There are numbers publicly available for how much blood people can safely donate(keywords: blood donation). That gives you one volume, you have the volume of your container to fill. Should be pretty simple to come up with how many humans to fill if doing a once and done.

Comment: Worth noting that if you fill a vat with mixed blood, Bad Things will happen (typically referred to as [agglutination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_compatibility_testing#History).)  Maybe this doesn't matter to your vampires, but I, for one, don't like drinking curdled milk.

Comment: I mean, sure...I could do this all on my own, but...here is a fun fact: There is a site to help worldbuilders on worldbuilding questions more complicated then 1+1=2 and can dragons breath fire. I was going to do just what you stated because I knew peeps were gonna complain about me not doing the math(I did do some in fact). @Pelinore

Comment: Well if reread my question you will see that they take out WAY over the safe amount. But fair enough, I guess I could do it on my own, but always good to get outside help on these things. @GaultDrakkor

Comment: Interesting. Is this just crossspecies or blood types? @jdunlop

Comment: @ConanHighwoods - blood types.  O won't agglutinate with anything, but A/B/AB will agglutinate if mixed.  This caused major problems even before attempting infusion in early blood donation.

Comment: Convert your tank measurements to its volume in cubic feet. Convert cubic feet to pints. Use Google to discover  number of pints in average human. Multiply by 0.9. That's the number of humans you need to immediately fill the tank. Divide by two to fill it in 6 days. Continue to divide until the time you want to wait is achieved. -1 for asking us to do basic math. VTC:Not About Worldbuilding for asking about something not related to a world rule.

Comment: Missed a step. Multiply by 0.9, divide into total needed pints.

Comment: Where did the 0.9 come from? @JBH

Comment: @ConanHighwoods 90% = 0.9, no? Perhaps 0.85 is slightly more accurate for a 80%-90% range

Comment: @ConanHighwoods It came from you. "This saliva lets them take up to around 80-90% of a human's blood without ill effect." I simply took the best-case (for filling the tank) value.

Comment: @ConanHighwoods There is the expectation that some research has been done, The question makes no acknowledgement of having done that with regard to volume of blood in a person either total or safe to donate values. Yet those values are core to the question as written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A lot of people

55.5 feet is just shy of 17m. 17m cubed is about 4913000 litres. Where I live, a man is allowed to give 0,5 litre 5 times a year, women 3 times. That is once every 2,4 months and 4 months respectively. The reason isn't that blood isn't replaced. A few days are enough. You're losing other important things that aren't replenished as quickly, of which iron is one of the more important that replenishes slowly.

If you would use people just once safely you would need 9826000 people, close to 10 million. A small country's worth. If we use only men for a slightly less than year we would need roughly 1965200 men.

With magic and recuperation we can probably scale that down, but let's suffice to say it feels like quite a lot.

I feel like I made a mistake somewhere, but that's what the comments are for. The rough numbers in this quick back-of-a-napkin math suggests that you need a city's worth of people at least to make it work, with heavy reliance on magic and industrial means of gathering blood.

Comment: Thanks, one of the only helpful users on this post.